# How to find a dynamic folders?

Tags: find, rm, aix

I created folder like this :

```
$folder_name=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
$mkdir -p ${DIR_LOG}/${folder_name}
```

Example of folders name: `[20160622]`, `[20160621]`...etc

Now I need to find those folders and delete them (folders are not empty) if they are 3 months older.
I tried to do this :

```
find ${DIR_LOG}/* -name "*.${folder_name}" -type d -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This only delete folders that have a current date and not other folders as (`20160621`).

Comment: Exactly, i need to specify only folders with this name type

Comment: Don't you want a plain `-name regex` in the `find` and not `-name "*.${folder_name}" `  with the backtick string?  In fact `-regex` would be better than `-name`

Comment: @Rahul Yes, their are other folders.

Comment: I want to say `find ${DIR_LOG} -regex '^\d{8}$' -type d -mtime +90`  but lack the wherewithal to test it at the moment

Comment: @infixed regex gives me the same result as -name

Comment: had to edit it to add the `mtime`

Comment: @aminetabenyoussef you want to delete those directory which starts with `2016..` and 3 months old ?

Comment: @Rahul My directory contains folder like 2016.. and other random folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this first to make sure it gets the desired dir's

```
find ${DIR_LOG} -type d -mtime +90 -name "20[0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

then run this to actually delete them.

```
find ${DIR_LOG} -type d -mtime +90 -name "20[0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It said that "bad option -regextype"

Comment: What version of find do you have? `find -version`

Comment: I'm on aix machine i think -regextype not works

Comment: Okay I don't have an AIX machine to test with but I updated the answer with a more generic/compatible syntax